# Make Gravatar images be requested using https

Tags: feature-request

How about making the gravatar images be requested as `https` instead of `http`?

In fact we are facing some problems in some countries that gravatar images do not display (timeout or just don't load) if they are requested normally using http. This is because some ISPs block some websites or filter some requests, and Gravatar seem to be newly included :(

Is it possible to make them be requested using `https`, so that blocking/filtering will no longer affect them (at least in my country, I'm sure `https` will solve the problem). I don't think it has any overload on the side of SE servers.

P.S: It would be very nice to apply this on the whole SE network and not only Islam.SE.

Comment: If you're experience performance issues with `http`, it will only get worse with `https`.

Comment: It affects performance on the server side, but has almost no effect on the network/client AFAIK.

Comment: Actually the performance hit is general: Data is encrypted in the server side (takes time), transmitted in encrypted form over the network (data is bigger, hence the transmission time is longer), and then decrypted in the client side (again, takes time). It's _not_ a significant performance hit, and typically it might not even be noticeable, however you say that you are already having performance issues with `http` requests, `https` will only make those worse. Perhaps not noticeably worse, but definitely not better...

Comment: @YannisRizos: Perhaps I clarify well: my problem is neither with performance nor with internet speed. It's that the ISP blocks some websites/requests (or slows them intentionally) if he knows what they are. Usuing `https` will hide that and photos will be displayed normally.

Comment: The browser extension `HTTPS Everywhere` might help you.

Comment: This should probably be requested on meta.stackoverflow.com. Although I suspect it's a bit of a long-shot.

Answer (score 2):

HTTPS has performance implications; it's generally slower / consumes more resources than HTTP.

That asside, HTTPS prevents "man in the middle" attacks -- when you don't want someone to intercept your messages. It doesn't make sense to apply it to gravatars.

Comment: It also prevents the ISP from knowing what you are really requesting, this is the main thing I need to get images displayed in my country.

Comment: @TamerShlash That's a good reason to ask for `https` requests on gravatars, please update your question to include it.